# Getting issue of Javascript TypeError while using window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase method of Cordova SQLite Plugin

Tags: javascript, sqlite, cordova

I'm using cordova-sqlite-plugin for maintaining a localdatabase for my application. Below is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/cordova.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
     alert("Running...")
     document.addEventListener("deviceready",function(){
          window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({
               name: 'test.db',
               iosDatabaseLocation: 'default'
          }, function(db){
                  alert('Database Created');
     });
</script>
```

});

Below is the screenshot of the error which I'm getting while running the same on xcode simulator

[image: Error getting while running the script]

It will be a great help if anyone can suggest some best possible solution.

Answer (score 1):

Need to add SQLitePlugin.js also in the HTML like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/cordova.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/SQLitePlugin.js"></script>
```

SQLitePlugin.js can be found in www folder inside cordova-sqlite-storage plugin folder (cordova-sqlite-plugin->www->SQLitePlugin.js)